# Run different pre-commit hooks on different lists of files

Tags: static-analysis, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am trying to progressively add linting and automatic code formatting to a legacy codebase.

For now, I am just running all the hooks on the same list of "cleaned" files.

This is my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file:

```
files: |
    (?x)^(
        mymodule/tests/.*py|
        mymodule/cleanfile1.py|
        mymodule/cleanfile2.py
    )$
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.9.3
    hooks:
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (python)
        args: [--profile=black]
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (cython)
        types: [cython]
        args: [--profile=black]
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (pyi)
        types: [pyi]
        args: [--profile=black]
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        args:
        -   --max-line-length=88
        -   --ignore=E203,E501,E731,E741,W503,SIM106,SIM119,FS002,FS003
        additional_dependencies:
        -   flake8-comprehensions
        -   flake8-mutable
        -   flake8-simplify
        -   flake8-use-fstring
```

I would like to change this so that `isort` and `black` are run on all files, and the whitelist based selection of cleaned files applies only to `flake8`.

Is there a way to do this? I tried moving the `files` block to a subsection of the `flake8` config, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[WARNING] Unexpected key(s) present on https://github.com/pycqa/flake8: files
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: the files selection can be done independently for each hook

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.9.3
    hooks:
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (python)
        args: [--profile=black]
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (cython)
        types: [cython]
        args: [--profile=black]
    -   id: isort
        name: isort (pyi)
        types: [pyi]
        args: [--profile=black]
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
-   repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        args:
        -   --max-line-length=88
        -   --ignore=E203,E501,E731,E741,W503,SIM106,SIM119,FS002,FS003
        additional_dependencies:
        -   flake8-comprehensions
        -   flake8-mutable
        -   flake8-simplify
        -   flake8-use-fstring
        files: |
          (?x)^(
              mymodule/tests/.*py|
              mymodule/cleanfile1.py|
              mymodule/cleanfile2.py
          )$
```

My error was caused by bad indentation. I initially tried to add `files`  at the same level as `hooks`, `repo` and `rev` when they need to be a subargument of `hooks`.